# Spring Security Siteminder + username password authentication

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, siteminder

I am working on implementing security for a web application using Spring Security. The web application will also be protected using SiteMinder. I have read the [Pre-authentication scenarios](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/preauth.html) of Spring Security reference document and believe I understand it. My problem is that the same **instance** of web application should be available to a subset of users (different URL / web server) without SiteMinder protection but instead using regular username/password authentication. I was wondering if this is something that can be easily achieved using Spring Security and how.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! What have you tried so far? [Questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) without a [clear problem statement](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) are not useful to other readers; see if you can be more specific with your question.

Comment: Your question is vague because you haven't tried anything. Spring Security is powerful and I am pretty sure what you want can be achieved. But you can just ask "How" here. You have to try first and if you get stuck come here with the issue.